# Which version of openssl should I use?

Tags: openssl

Three different versions of openssl are being concurrently updated on [openssl.org](http://openssl.org): 0.98, 1.0.0, 1.0.1?  What's the difference between them, and how do I go about choosing which version to use?

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL

Has an easy readable table in timeline order.

Answer (score 0):

To know the difference between versions, you can look at change log of OpenSSL [here](http://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html).
To know how 1.0.0 is different, just see the entries below "Changes between 0.9.8n and 1.0.0  [29 Mar 2010]".

Some of the difference for example support for name constraints certificate extension.
To know the difference between 1.0.0h and 1.0.1 see Changes between 1.0.0h and 1.0.1  [14 Mar 2012].

Criteria for choosing OpenSSL version: It depends all on your use. For example, if you want to use GCM for TSL, then you need to use 1.0.0.

This change log will be helpful for you in identifying which version to use.